# How can I prevent valgrind from reporting static variables as leaks?

Tags: c, valgrind, c99

I sometimes use static variables to only do expensive initialization if the function is actually called, and to avoid initializing every call.  For example...

```
#include <glib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool is_blank(char *line) {
    static GRegex *blank_line_re = NULL;

    if( !blank_line_re ) {
        blank_line_re = g_regex_new(
            "^ \\s* $",
            G_REGEX_OPTIMIZE | G_REGEX_EXTENDED,
            0,
            NULL
        );
    }

    return g_regex_match(blank_line_re, line, 0, NULL);
}
```

Unfortunately valgrind will report them as memory leaks.  I don't consider static variables to be memory leaks.

How can I prevent valgrind from reporting static variables as memory leaks without having to put in special suppressions for each one?

Alternatively, is there a better pattern in C to avoid reinitialization?

Comment: Does `valgrind` report it as a leak or as 'still reachable'?  I get still reachable for loosely similar code (not using glib, but with a static variable pointing at allocated memory).  If you're going to fret about the still reachable, I think you have to make it a file static instead of function static variable, and you can then register an `atexit()` function to release the memory.  As the program is exiting anyway, it isn't clear that it's necessary to release that memory, though it is tidiest.

Comment: Yes, "still reachable". And I agree it's not necessary to free the memory, but it makes memory leak reports harder to interpret. And I wasn't familiar with `atexit()`! Thank you!

Comment: @Schwern In fact, you should mostly care about "definitely lost"; "still reachable" is not a problem, as it indicates that you "could have freed" it if you really wanted. The problem is "definitely lost", which indicates that you cannot free the memory at program exit, which is usually a bug. See also [the manual](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.leaks).

Comment: @JonasWielicki Good advice. I have `--show-leak-kinds` set to all. I'll experiment with turning it off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest thing to do is define variables like this at global or file scope, then clean them up in at [`atexit`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/atexit.3.html) handler.

```
struct s *s1 = NULL;
struct s *s2 = NULL;

void free_global(void)
{
    free(s1);
    free(s2);
}

...
void f1(void)
{
    s1 = malloc(sizeof(struct s));
}

void f2(void)
{
    s2 = malloc(sizeof(struct s));
}

...

int main(void)
{
    atexit(free_global);
    ...
    f1();
    ...
    f2();
    ...
}
```

If you want to get really fancy, you could have a global array of `void *` that keeps a copy of all static/global allocations so you can free them later, and make a function that takes the newly allocated pointer and adds it to the list.

Comment: I didn't know about `atexit`, I was looking for something like it. Thanks! Is there a way to have the library call `atexit` itself so the library user isn't responsible?

Comment: @Schwern I'm not familiar with this library, but if I had to guess I'd say probably not.  There may be times where you want to allocate/deallocate several times throughout your program, while other times you would allocate at the start and deallocate at the end like in this particular situation, so the library wouldn't know what has been freed already and what hasn't.

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to the library I'm writing. The one that contains `is_blank`. That function is happy to allocate on the first call and deallocate at program exit.

Comment: @Schwern In that case, yes you can do that.  You can call `atexit` either in an initialization function you expect the user to call, or in `is_blank` when the memory in question is first allocated.

Answer (score 3):

Glib requires you to call `g_regex_unref(GRegex *);` as soon as you're done with a regex. Therefore, you need some mechanism to make this call before your program is done.

You could either have a global list where you store the regex pointers to finally unref them, you can have the `GRegex *` pointer global where you can just use it to delete the obejct in the end, or you can refactor to have the pointer returned by a seperate function which you can use to unref.

```
GRegex * my_blank_reg()
{
  static GRegex *blank_line_re = NULL;
  if (!blank_line_re) 
  {
    blank_line_re = g_regex_new(
      "^ \\s* $", G_REGEX_OPTIMIZE | G_REGEX_EXTENDED,  
      0, NULL);
  }
  return blank_line_re;
}

bool is_blank(char *line) 
{
  return g_regex_match(my_blank_reg(), line, 0, NULL);
}

void free_static()
{
  g_regex_unref(my_blank_reg());
}

int main()
{
  // do stuff with is_blank()

  free_static();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Interesting pattern, thanks. I think between your answer and [dbush](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34689278/14660)'s I can cobble something together.

Answer (score 0):

Your *pointer* is static, but then you make it point to an allocated buffer by calling `g_regex_new()`, and *that* buffer has to be freed.

Comment: Ok. So how do I solve that problem? When/where does the free happen?

Comment: If `g_regex_new()` is the only way to build one of those objects, then you're stuck. They built the API expecting you to free them. If you have access to the structure, you can do `static GRegex blank_line_re = { ... };` (Note: no `*`), and fill in the structure members by hand. But I suspect it's a complex recursive structure that won't be easy.

Comment: [This is the function in question](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Perl-compatible-regular-expressions.html#g-regex-new), but it's just an example. Most API functions only provide struct pointers. Filling it in by hand will introduce compatibility problems, that's not an option.

Comment: You're use is something like a "lazy initialization" pattern: The first time the function is called, create the structure, then use it throughout the program. To free it at the end consider placing each such pointer you create on a "to be freed" list and call the `unref()` on each of the ones in that list at the end of `main()`.

Answer (score 0):

valgrind has a "suppression file" feature. It's a configuration file that instructs valgrind that certain memory allocations that it would otherwise report as leaks should be ignored.

In this case, you would specify, using the appropriate directives, that memory allocations from your `is_blank`() function, but not from any other function that `is_blank()` itself calls, perhaps, should be ignored.

You will find more information about suppression files in valgrind's documentation.

Comment: I have a suppression file. I would prefer not to have to add to it every time I use this pattern.

Comment: Sadly, valgrind is not clairvoyant and cannot figure out if the same function's logic won't try to allocate and overwrite the same pointer, thus truly leaking memory. Therefore, one has to work with valgrind, and teach it what it should or shouldn't ignore. Having to deal with sloppily third party libraries, written by inept developers, whose _dl_init() allocate static buffers without _dl_fini() freeing them, I agree that this is a pain. What can I say, life sucks. It is what it is, and I do not see any other realistic alternative.

Comment: @Schwern then you'll need to name such functions with a common pattern, and use wildcards in the suppression file.